# Set 'Emulate a focused Page' option in Chrome Developer Tools via console

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools

How can I set the 'Emulate a focused Page' option in Chrome Developer Tools using the Console?
Or can this be done somehow using IJavaScriptExecutor or configured in ChromeOptions?

I tried this option:

`IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver; IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@type='text']")); js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].focus(); document.activeElement = arguments[0];", element);`

Also here is this:

`js.ExecuteScript("Object.defineProperty(document, 'hasFocus', {value: () => true});");`

And here it is:

`window.dispatchEvent(new FocusEvent('focus'));`

And this:

`Object.defineProperty(document, 'hasFocus', { get: function() { return false; } });`